# How to inject ItemViewModel in tornadoFx

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I am trying to add model to view by injection

```
val model = PersonModel by inject()
```

but error:

> 'PersonModel' does not have a companion object.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `:`, not `=`.

```
val model: PersonModel by inject()
```

---

The reason for the error is that, when the compiler sees `val model = PersonModel`, it assumes you're trying to assign the companion object of the `PersonModel` class to `model`, but there isn't one, so it gives you the most helpful message it can, not realizing you made a simple syntax mistake.